# how to get size of compressed data from BZ2_bzBuffToBuffCompress

Tags: c++, compression

I want to compress a string and get the size of the compressed data... but regardless of what string I pass to my function, it always returns the same result: 39.  Any advice is greatly appreciated.

```
int compressedLength(char * source){
ostringstream oss;
int blockSize100k = 9;
        int verbosity = 0;
        int workFactor = 30; // 0 = USE THE DEFAULT VALUE
        unsigned int sourceLength = sizeof(source);
        unsigned int destLength = 1.01 * sourceLength + 600;    // Official formula, Big enough to hold output.  Will change to real size.
        char *dest = (char*)malloc(destLength);
        int returnCode = BZ2_bzBuffToBuffCompress( dest, &destLength, source, sourceLength, blockSize100k, verbosity, workFactor );

        if (returnCode == BZ_OK)
        {
                free(dest);
                return destLength;
        }
        else
        {
                free(dest);
                cout << " Can't get compressed length. " << "Error code:" << returnCode;
                return returnCode;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is here:

```
    unsigned int sourceLength = sizeof(source);
```

That will always be 4 or 8 (depending on whether your machine has 32-bit or 64-bit pointers), not the actual length of the data buffer you sent in.  If the data buffer you sent in is a C string, then you need to use either `strlen(source)` or `strlen(source) + 1`, depending on whether you want to include the terminating NUL.

If the buffer is *not* a C string, then you need to pass the actual size of the buffer to your `compressedLength()` function, since it otherwise has no way to find out its size.

Comment: @user1971455 : If this solved your issue, consider up-voting this answer and marking it as "accepted".